# How to update Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus phone apps via USB cable connection?

Tags: updates, samsung, windows

I cant seem to be able to connect to the software update server for some reason by using my basic 3G connection (which works by the way).

The error message goes as follows:
"Failed to update software. Network or server error occurred. Try later or try using PC Kies.". I tried several times with same error.

So I was thinking if it could be possible to update my Samsung Galaxy Trend Plus phone apps via USB connection through my computer network?

I tried Samsung Kies, but couldn't find any feature to support this.

My PC has Windows 7 installed on it if that matters.